# Delete Row from Google Sheets, based on multiple column values as criterea

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to delete rows from google sheets based on multiple column data as criterea.

My Code is like this
(Trigger is onFormSubmit)

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
    var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

    //find each matching row and "blank it"
    for ( var i = 0; i<rg.length; ++i ) {
        if ( rg[i][1] === rg[i][2] && rg[i][3] == 25) {
            sh.getRange(i+1,1,1,5).setValues([["","","","",""]]);  //,,setValues array might need changing
        }
    }

    //find the blank rows and delete them
    for ( var i = 0; i<rg.length; ++i ) {
        if ( rg[i][0] == "" ) {
            sh.deleteRow(rg[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

When new data comes in, it is just checking for File token value = 25. I need the script to check for all values. This is just sample test data and not actual data. Also it is deleting only values, and leaving a blank row when subsequent data comes in. I need it to delete the row, and not just the values.

Comment: Tx for yoour response. But ur code is also deleting just  the Last row uploaded. It needs to delete ALL rows where File token Value is SAME as the File Token Value in Row where Column B = Column C

Comment: this is exactly what it does. I didn't change the conditions in the if statement. The code deletes **ALL** the rows when: Column B = Column C **and** Column D = 25. Check the code again.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- In your current solution, when the first if condition evaluates to
  true, you `clear` the cells and then you use a second if condition to
  `delete` the rows that have blank cells.
- Instead, you can just `delete` the rows when the first if condition is
  met.
- Last but not least, you need to delete rows **backwards** because every time you delete a row starting from the top, the order of the data won't correspond to the correct row.

**Side Notes:**

- You want to delete row `i+1` because the array indexes start with 0. Namely, `rg[0]` is the first row.
- Also, [deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition) accepts the row position as an argument, not a row of values.

---

### Solution:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

//find each matching row and delete it
  for (var i = rg.length -1 ; i > 0; i--) {
      if ( rg[i][1] === rg[i][2] && rg[i][3] == 25) {
             sh.deleteRow(i+1);
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reach your goal is by doing a O(n^2) search. Keep in mind that each deletion changes the indexes in your Sheet.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  //find each matching row and "blank it"
  for ( var i = 1; i < rg.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j = i+1; j < rg.length; j++ ) {
      if ( (rg[j][1] === rg[j][2] && rg[j][3] === rg[i][3]) || rg[j][0] === '') {
        rg.splice(j, 1);
        sh.deleteRow(j+1);
        j--;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this and revert. Thank you.